# How to know for which alias name, the module is loaded, when there are multiple aliases?

Tags: usb, kernel-modules, modprobe

When I run the command:

```
cat /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/modules.alias | grep 'ath9k_htc'
```

I get the following list:

```
alias usb:v0CF3p20FFd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0930p0A08d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v04DAp3904d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0411p0197d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0411p017Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v083ApA704d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0846p9018d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0CF3p7010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v1668p1200d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0CF3p7015d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v1EDAp2315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0471p209Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v057Cp8403d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0CF3pB002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0CF3pB003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v040Dp3801d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v04CAp4605d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v13D3p3350d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v13D3p3349d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v13D3p3348d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v13D3p3346d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v13D3p3328d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v13D3p3327d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v07D1p3A10d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0846p9030d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0CF3p1006d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
alias usb:v0CF3p9271d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
```

I want to know for which alias name - `usb:***`, the module gets loaded when i plugin my usb device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is formatted with the vendor and product id

e.g.

```
alias usb:v0CF3p9271d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* ath9k_htc
```

Has Vendor ID of 0CF3 and a Product ID of 9271

You can use `lsusb` to see which device you have plugged into your machine has matching vendor/product ids.